# WPFToolkit Datagrid Override within a User Control? Subclass help please

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I'm having some trouble with subclassing and overriding WPFToolkit DataGrid events within a custom WPF Control. **This is all for WPF on .NET Framework 3.5**

My XAML is similar to the following

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyGUI.EM.DocChecklistView"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit">

<Grid>
        <toolkit:DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DocVS}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Name="_dgDoc" Margin="0,0,0,46">
```

The code is something similar to

```
public partial class DocChecklistView:  UserControl, IDataModuleView {     

        protected override System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public CDocumentChecklistView() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

However, note the first override in the code - that never fires. That makes sense since I'm not subclassing the DataGrid (WPFToolkit). How can I modify this code to include a subclass to the DataGrid and make sure the override fires???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom DataGrid control.

```
public class CustomDataGrid:  DataGrid
{   
    protected override System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you use that control in your view instead of the DataGrid.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyGUI.EM.DocChecklistView"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
    xmlns:yourControl="clr-namespace:YourNamespace">

    <Grid>
        <yourControl:CustomDataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DocVS}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Name="_dgDoc" Margin="0,0,0,46">
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it besides this? Since my grid is in a user control, there's a lot of other commands and bindings and what-not that exist that make the solution you proposed very difficult. I'd rather do it using my existing class and a subclass of the DataGrid

Comment: All your other commands and bindings shouldn't need to be changed. Pull the override method out of your codebehind and put it in a class inheriting from datagrid. Use your inherited datagrid in place of the existing datagrid. That should be the extent of the changes.